# Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I made some code that wouldn't work. An error popped up in the Chrome console saying "Syntax error: Unexpected identifier". Error is on line 19. Here is the code:

```
13.      var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas")
14.      var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d")
15.      function getMousePos(canvas,evt){
16.          var rect=canvas.getBindingClientRect()
17.          return{
18.               x:evt.clientX-rect.left
19.               y:evt.clientY-rect.top
20.          }
21.      }
22.      canvas.addEventListener("mouseclick",function(evt){
23.           var mousePos=getMousePos(canvas,evt)
24.           ctx.fillRect(mousePos.x-15,mousePos.y-15,10,10)
25.      },false)
```

Comment: add a comma on line 18

Comment: Add semicolons at the end of every logical line. Javascript interpeters are pretty good at guessing where the semi-colons ought to go, but they do get it wrong.

Comment: ok, was not worthy as answer :)

Comment: Jslint.com for the love OF GOD!

Comment: @thg435: actually, line 19 might be better...  Seriously though, basic debugging would get that bug straight off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from line 17:
add a comma on line 18 as @thg435 mentioned

```
return {
  x:evt.clientX-rect.left,
  y:evt.clientY-rect.top  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected Identifier error mostly occurs, when you are, misspelling a keyword like `var`,`let`,`const` etc or having an extra or missing a Comma `,` or Semicolon`;`.

In your code, in line 17, you're outputting a object, an object's value must be comma separated (like arrays). So, you forgot a comma at the end of line 18, that's why this error occurred

```
return{
  x:evt.clientX-rect.left,
  y:evt.clientY-rect.top
}
```